# Python get function adds

Tags: python, dictionary

I was trying to read an example when i stumbled upon a form i couldn't quite understand:

```
my_values = parse_qs("red=5&blue=0&green=", keep_blank_values=True)

opacity = my_values.get("opacity", [""])[0] or 0
```

The code was calling a dict i made and made a parameter for when the value is missing then added "[0] or 0" part to the code which i couldn't understand how it works

So i tried to run the code asking for a key that wasn't there to run the parameter and it gave me zero as an answer to my unidentified key

when i tried to run the same code without **"[0] or 0"** part it gave an empty list "**[""]**" for the unknown key and when i removed the "**or 0**" part the answer changed to just this **""**

So what functionality is this? so i can read more about it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please update your question with a small sample of the data in `my_values`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think it would be relevant, will try to be more detailed later

Comment: the code is copied from the site but of course feel free to check
https://hacktec.gitbooks.io/effective-python/content/en/Chapter1/Item4.html
and there is no () around that part not in my question nor the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code `some_dict.get("some_key", [""])[0] or 0` have 3 working parts, lets dissect them

First, lets start with the `or` part, [*or*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) is a boolean operator (of the same name), and can also be looked at as the following function

```
def or_(a,b):
    if bool(a):
        return a
    else:
        return b
```

(but unlike the function version it have the capability of short-circuit)

```
>>> 1 or 2
1
>>> 0 or 2
2
>>> "hello" or "world"
'hello'
>>> "" or "world"
'world'
>>> "hello" or 0
'hello'
>>> "" or 0
0
```

as for the short-circuit, it means that the second expression isn't evaluated if the first is [Truth](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

```
>>> 1 or 1/0 # no error here because 1/0 isn't evaluated
1
>>> 0 or 1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    0 or 1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

The second part is the [.get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) in  some_dict.get("some_key", [""]), that is the same as some_dict["some_key"] but without the throwing KeyError on a missing key and instead returning the second argument (if given, None otherwise), your default value, that in this case is [""]

```
>>> some_dict = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
>>> some_dict.get("a",32)
1
>>> some_dict.get("xxx",32)
32
>>>
```

And finally the [0] and the end of some_dict.get("some_key", [""])[0], here there is an implicit assumption that whatever you get from the dict is something you can index, like a list, tuple, string, etc. and you want the first element of it, that is why the second argument for .get is a list with a single element, so even in the case when the key is missing, your default value is a list with a single element, so you get that at the end

```
>>> some_dict = {"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5],"c":[6]}
>>> some_dict.get("a",[""])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> some_dict.get("a",[""])[0]
1
>>> some_dict.get("xxx",[""])
['']
>>> some_dict.get("xxx",[""])[0]
''
>>>
```

So with all that combined, then you get either the first element of the value for that key if it is truth or 0 if not or is missing

Comment: Thanks a lot this have been most helpful and generous, really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

This is an occasional pattern used to handle falsy values and *also* non-existent keys in a dictionary. For instance,

```py
>>> d1 = {"opacity": ""}
>>> d2 = {"opacity": None}
>>> d3 = {}
>>> d1.get("opacity") or 0
0
>>> d2.get("opacity") or 0
0
>>> d3.get("opacity") or 0
0
```

All 3 of them give you the same result without throwing a key error.

Comment: Thanks for the response, what about the [0] part before the or in the code? what exactly is its function? and is there a term to cover the expression so i can read about it?

Comment: It's just array index ?

Comment: It might be although i would think that it is uncalled for as there single values for the keys not lists that is why it didn't occur to me, thanks alot for the help

Answer (score 0):

Given `my_values` as you defined them, the following is its value-

```
{'red': ['5'], 'blue': ['0'], 'green': ['']}
```

```
>>> my_values.get("red", [""])
['5']
>>> my_values.get("red", [""])[0]
'5'
>>> my_values.get("opacity", [""])
[""]
>>> my_values.get("opacity", [""])[0]
""
```

So the expresion you want is probably `my_values.get(color, [""])[0]` or `my_values.get(color, [None])[0]`, which will return `None` if the color is not found.

Comment: Thanks for the response, The answer that i want concerned the zero response for unidentified keys, which the other commenter so generously offered. Thanks